# make the gwt celltable row selected

Tags: gwt

I have a cell Table in GWT with columns , there are 3 rows in each column, I want the first row to get selected by default when the application starts

some thing like this

```
                 mycelltable.setselectedrow(index);
```

is it possible ?

Thanks

her is the code

```
                      display.getShortListedCVsBasedOnJob().getResumeDescriptionColumn().setFieldUpdater(

            new FieldUpdater<CandidateSummary, String>() {
                public void update(int index, CandidateSummary object,
                        String value) {

                    fetchResume(cvSelected, shortListedFlag);
                }
            });
```

This fetchResume() method calls but only when i select cell of this column , I want to call this fetchResume() method as my application starts, i.e i want to make the 1st cell of the column to be selected byDefault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could work?

```
setSelected(Element elem, boolean selected)
```

see GWT Documentation

[CellTable Google Web Toolkit](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html)

Hmm I dont see what´s the Celltable is there. I would set the initial Value like this:

```
int INITAL_SET_ROW = 0;
TableRowElement initalSetElement = yourCellTable.getRowElement(INITAL_SET_ROW);
yourCellTable.setSelected(initialSetElement, true);
```

You can try to implement it in you´re main Method. Haven´t tested it tho, hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, u r right , but setselected is the property of selectionmodel but i don't have something selected when the application starts, so have null object at the time

Comment: thanks, yourCellTable.setSelected(initialSetElement, true); is not visible , i mean when i write mycelltable.    there's nothing like setselected ..?  (i am using gwt2.4)

Comment: you mean in codesuggestions in eclipse? Is the correct Class imported?

Comment: Yes,  which class should be imported ?

Comment: after you type setSeletected(...) check if you import the GWT Cell Table (CTRL + SHIFT + o) in eclipse and select the GWT Cell Table.

Answer (score 6):

Selection is handled by a `SelectionModel`, based on objects (not indices); so you have to select the first object from your data in the `SelectionModel` used by the `CellTable` (have a look at the *Using a key provider to track objects as they change* sample code in the [`Celltable` javadoc](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html) for an example (last sample before *nested classes summary*).

Answer (score 0):

Simply;

```
List<RowType> source = new LinkedList<RowType>(); 
//put some data to this list
//populate the table
table.setRowCount(source.size(), true);
table.setRowData(0, source);
//for example, you can select the first row
RowType firstRow = source.get(0);
selectionModel.setSelected(firstRow, true);
```